# Using Redact Policy in API Connect 2018

Tags: apiconnect, apic

I have the below message from where I want to remove the field "Status Code"

```
{
    "Details": {
        "UT_LL": 22235,
        "UT_ZZ": 512,
        "Status Code": 206,
        "UT_DATE": "2019-10-02-11.36.16.353965",
        "UT_TOTAL_REC": 132
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help as I am new to API connect. Also kindly note that I have already went through IBM portal and Knowledge center for the same use case..But none of those options work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you already solved, as it has been some time since this post. But nevertheless the solution for the wider community.

I was using API Connect 2018.4.1.9 (but should work same with earlier versions too) and was using DataPower API Gateway Service

1] I created a mock endpoint to respond with the above JSON data

2] Response w/o redact policy

```
{
    "Details": {
        "UT_LL": 22235,
        "UT_ZZ": 512,
        "Status Code": 206,
        "UT_DATE": "2019-10-02-11.36.16.353965",
        "UT_TOTAL_REC": 132
    }
}
```

3] Response with redact policy. As you could see the Status Code field is removed (redacted), you could choose

```
{
  "Details": {
    "UT_LL": 22235,
    "UT_ZZ": 512,    
    "UT_DATE": "2019-10-02-11.36.16.353965",
    "UT_TOTAL_REC": 132
  }
}
```

API Yaml file i used.

https://github.com/pramodvallanur/samples/blob/master/redact-sample.yaml

Comment: Thanks for the response Pramodh..I tried and it worked..However if I want to redact more than one field can I do that by adding comma after each field? like message.body.Details."Status Code", message.body.Details."UT_DATE"